# Protect mini-split condenser from ocean corrosion?

Tags: air-conditioning, central-air, rust-proofing, rust

I recently bought an A/C inverter and put the condenser on the roof. I live next to the ocean so if I don't do something to protect it, *something* in the blower will start rusting very soon.

What can I do to protect it from the salt-packed air that literally rusts everything?

The blower looks like this:
[image: blower]

Comment: What make and model is the mini-split outdoor unit? You are correct to be concerned about coil corrosion, by the way...

Comment: If you're close enough to the ocean, the best option is to interchange with ocean water instead of air.  Or groundwater.  Equipment made to interchange with ocean water is, obviously, built for that.

Comment: Coating the fins can greatly extend the life. https://www.achrnews.com/articles/96333-the-salt-air-nemesis-and-solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that there's much you can do to protect it. The condenser's job is to exhaust the heat from inside your home so you can't really enclose it.

Having looked around some, the only thing I've seen that's of a DIY nature is to rinse your condenser on a regular basis. Maybe rig up a sprinkler with a hose and let it spray the condenser. That should keep some of the salt out and hopefully prolong the life of your unit. Beyond that, regular professional maintenance was the other common suggestion.